# How to get values from table data of same class name and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which contains team names and scores. I have made a demo here **[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/w7p9nv50/)**

When I click the Submit button, it will show the output of one match only (Team A and B only) but not the other matches.

Since they all share the same class name for the name and score, How to go on about that?

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr data-match="match1">
    <td class="team1n">Team A</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="ts1" class="ts1" value="3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="ts2" value="1">
    </td>
    <td class="team2n">Team B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-match="match2">
    <td class="team1n">Team C</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="ts1" value="2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="ts2" value="3">
    </td>
    <td class="team2n">Team D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-match="match3">
    <td class="team1n">Team E</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="ts1" value="2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="ts2" value="1">
    </td>
    <td class="team2n">Team F</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="sprd">Submit</button>

<div class="textbox"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#sprd").click(function() {
    const matchid = $('tr').data("match");
    const team1n = $('.team1n:eq(0)').text();
    const team1s = parseInt($(".ts1:eq(0)").val());
    const team2n = $('.team2n:eq(0)').text();
    const team2s = parseInt($(".ts2:eq(0)").val());

    $('.textbox').append(team1n + " --- " + "<b>"+ team1s+ "</b>"+ " - " + "
<b>"+ team2s+ "</b> --- "+ team2n);

});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fbx21vLc/

Comment: thanks.. post it as answer if you want @Chris g so I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop each tr elemnt in table and then get values , after puttinh them in result , after the loop render the result .

See below snippet :

```js
$("#sprd").click(function() {
  var result = "";
  $("table tr").each(function(index,el) {
    var match = $(el).data("match");
     result +="<div class='macth'>"+match+"</div>";
    var team1 = $(el).find('.team1n').text();
    var team2 = $(el).find('.team2n').text();
    var score1 = $(el).find('.ts1').val();
    var score2 = $(el).find('.ts2').val();
    result += '<div>'+team1+ " --- " + "<b>" + score1 + "</b>" + " - " + "<b>" + score2 + "</b> --- " + team2+'</div>';
  });

  $('.textbox').html(result);

});
```

```css
.macth {
  color:green;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:15px;
}

.textbox  {
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-match="match1">
    <td class="team1n">Team A</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="ts1" class="ts1" value="3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="ts2" value="1">
    </td>
    <td class="team2n">Team B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-match="match2">
    <td class="team1n">Team C</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="ts1" value="2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="ts2" value="3">
    </td>
    <td class="team2n">Team D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-match="match3">
    <td class="team1n">Team E</td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="ts1" value="2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="ts2" value="1">
    </td>
    <td class="team2n">Team F</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="sprd">Submit</button>

<div class="textbox">

</div>
```

Comment: bRIMOs thanks and what about the data-match data in <tr> which is for database purpose.. how do I also show it

Comment: hey @user7716943 just get its value by using `.data("match")` or `.attr('data-match')` see my updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks @bRIMOs for sorting it out.

Comment: You're welocme My pleasure :)